# SwiftUI is not respecting safe area for Apple Watch

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch

I'm coding a standalone app for Apple Watch using SwiftUI. I'm creating a menu and the elements does not respect the safe area so the top of the circles I use is cut by a black bar. How can I fix this ?

[image]

```
struct Menu: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 30) {
                VStack {
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color.blue)
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                        Text("20")
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                    Text("Timer")
                }

                VStack {
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color.blue)
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                        Image(systemName: "hand.raised.fill")
                    }
                    Text("Tuto")
                }
            }

            HStack(spacing: 30) {
                VStack {
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color.blue)
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                        Image(systemName: "alarm.fill")
                    }
                    Text("Reminder")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say it is exactly in safe area. Just don't hardcode frames.

Comment: It works ! I deleted the .frame(width: 60, height: 60) and it is all good. Thank you !